# Integers which can be written as sum of powers of $2,3$, and $5$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it true that every sufficiently large integer can be written in the form 
$$
2^a3^b5^c+2^d3^e5^f
$$
for some integer $a,b,c,d,e,f \ge 0$?

Comment: Given that each exponent is allowed to be $0$, it is true that  every sufficiently small integer ($\ge 2$) can be so represented.

Comment: @KeithBackman Are you trolling?

Comment: Not at all. I saw Robert Israel's answer, and I tried to find any other small integers that could not be so represented, and found I could construct every integer up to $70$ but not $71$. Just a paper and pencil check on the given answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not the case.  The number of such possible sums $\le N$ for large $N$ is far less than $N$.

The number of powers of $2$ (or of $3$ or $5$) up to $N$ is $O(\log N)$.  Hence the number of products $2^a 3^b 5^c$ up to $N$ is $O((\log N)^3)$.  The number of sums of pairs of such products is $O((\log N)^6)$, which is $o(N)$.

Answer (score 1):

No numbers congruent to $71$ or $119$ mod $120$ can be represented in this way.